# App Inventor 2 minusing value by the whole contents of a list

Tags: app-inventor

I was wondering if there was a way to minus one value by the contents of the whole list in App Inventor.

For example if list1 = [4, 5, 4, 5] and I want to do let's say  the subtraction of 7 - 4 - 5 - 4 - 5, how could I do this in App Inventor 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a `procedure` to sum up the list and then calculate `7 - sumOfList` like this

[image]

Do the [tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php).